# проблема с типом данных в массиве

Tags: python

у меня проблема

```
ask = int(input("h"))

h = [0]*ask

h[1],h[2]=1,1
print(h[0],type(h[0]),h[1],type(h[1]))

for i in range(2,ask):


    h[i]= int()
    h[i]= h[i-1]+h[i-2]

    if type(h[i] ** 0.5)  != float():
        
        print(type(h[i] ** 0.5))
        print(h[i])
```

Этот код выводит `ask` чисел фибоначи и проверяет их на целый квадратный корень(например если попадает число 144 и квадратный корень из него является целым то 144 выводится принтом), но я не знаю что делать т.к. думаю что условие в if написал неправильно и тип выводимых данных float, как можно исправить проблему с типом float и ифом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корень всегда будет числом с плавающей точкой. Проверяйте лучше, что остаток от деления на 1 равен 0, это нормально работает для проверки целых чисел:

```py
if h[i] ** 0.5 % 1 == 0:
   ...
```

Другой вариант: брать целую часть от корня, возводить её обратно в квадрат, и проверять, что получилось то же, что и было до всех этих манипуляций:

```py
if int(h[i] ** 0.5) ** 2 == h[i]:
    ...
```

Тоже самое можно чуть проще делать с использованием функции пакета `math`:

```py
import math

if math.isqrt(h[i]) ** 2 == h[i]:
    ...
```

Comment: Наверное, лучше использовать специальный метод: `float.is_integer(self, /) Return True if the float is an integer.` И как по мне, самый идеальный способ проверить число на целый квадрат - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489540/14070318).

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T Хороший вариант! Добавьте свой ответ, я правда не уверен, что это всё тут не дубликат какого-то ответа на русском СО, мне проще заново ответы писать, чем искать дубли )

Comment: Первый способ не работает: `(70000000 ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5 % 1 == 0.0`. Тоже для `is_integer`: `((70000000 ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5).is_integer() == True`. Число выбрано так чтобы оно было точно представлено во `float`. Не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Возведение в дробную степень возвращает всегда `float`, поэтому для проверки чисел на полный квадрат лучше использовать этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489540/14070318):

```py
import math

def is_square(number: int) -> bool:
    return number == math.isqrt(number) ** 2
```

Comment: А почему вы в своём ответе про `float.is_integer` не написали? Я что-то запутался ))

Comment: @CrazyElf Он тут бесполезен)